# Auctex+sumatraPDF on Windows inverse search. want to remove the CMD windows

Tags: auctex, pdf

I am using Auctex+SumatraPDF on Windows now. I have set them working well, except a small annoying thing.

Every time I do the inverse search from SumatraPDF to Emacs, a Windows command window show up and disappear soon. I've already used --no-wait option in SumatraPDF, but still I can't get rid of the black window completely.

Is there anything I can do to remove it completely, though it is not a big deal.

Comment: This happens even without AUCTeX.  I suspect the solution will be at the Windows system level -- i.e., some sort of run in background configuration; or, perhaps the maintainers of SumatraPDF would have a better idea of how to resolve this issue.  If an answer is not forthcoming in a reasonable period of time on emacs.stackexchange.com, consider filing an issue with the maintainers of SumatraPDF.

Comment: Indeed, fully take your point. Thanks anyway